# mongoose + multiple records insert or update based on input

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the user collection like below(added few fields only for reference). i am using mongoose npm module.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   user_name: String,
   email: String,
   status: String
});
```

I am trying to insert/update multiple records in one query.

I am aware using insertMany functions we can insert multiple records:

Sample input:

```
[
  {
    user_name: 'test1',
    email: 'test1@gmail.com',
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    user_name: 'test1',
    email: 'test2@gmail.com',
    status: 'active'
  }
]
```

Query:

```
Users.insertMany(documents);
```

Question 1:
It's possible to insert/update multiple records in one query.I added sample for 2 records input..

```
[
  {
    user_name: 'test3',
    email: 'test1@gmail.com',
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    _id: '5fb63d1695998716c82506be',
    status: 'de-active'
  }
]
```

I'ts possible i can insert test3 user record and update for 2nd (reference _id) user records in one query?

Question 2:

It's possible to update multiple records in single query.

Input:

```
[
  {
    _id: '5fb63d1695998716c82506bd',
    user_name: 'test3',
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    _id: '5fb63d1695998716c82506be',
    status: 'de-active'
  }
]
```

Possible to update for first record(status,user_name) and 2nd record for status filed?

I can do it with two queries(1. insert query, 2. update query)

Answer (score 0):

There is no branching updates.

As you are aware, it has to be two queries.

update works this way. It has three parts.

1. Criteria to find the doc
2. Document to set when a doc matches the criteria
3. Update options.

You have options to update multiple documents, etc. There is no way to do the mapping i.e matching doc with id has to use this $set, matching doc with id2 has to use another $set doc.

Comment: So, we need to execute a query to update each record?

Comment: using promise all.

Comment: No, you can update many documents with same set of data

Comment: Nope. I have an array of objects with the _id key.. So I need to update the data differently filed with each list.. sample input:, here i needs to update 1st record user_name, id. 2nd record only update status column, only..   [
  {
    _id: '5fb63d1695998716c82506bd',
    user_name: 'test3',
    status: 'active'
  },
  {
    _id: '5fb63d1695998716c82506be',
    status: 'de-active'
  }
]

Comment: For now I am trying to use bulkwrite.. But I triying to find any other good solution.

Comment: Yes, bulk write is the best option when you need bulk write and it can have different update statements. That would suit your condition.